# Drawing the RG flow diagram

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization

In real-space renormalization group how does one find the complete RG flow exactly, (not schematically)? I understand it needs to be done on a computer. For example, I have the ising model on a triangular lattice and I also get the RG recursion relations by blocking ( as done in Nigel Goldenfeld's book). Now how do I get the smooth RG flow over the full parameter space?